# why is Graph API Update not working but other functions working

Tags: http, web, microsoft-graph-api, patch

Hello i am getting an error when using Microsoft graph api, i am getting a 403 error when I am updating a planner task.

> StatusCode:403,
>     ReasonPhrase:'Forbidden',
>      Version:1.1,
>      Content:System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
>      Headers:{
>         Transfer-Encoding:      chunked request-id:7      c6e6c64-60e8-4d65-a248-c91841f8f8ca client-request-id:7      c6e6c64-60e8-4d65-a248-c91841f8f8ca x-ms-ags-diagnostic:{
>            "ServerInfo":{
>               "DataCenter":"North Europe",
>               "Slice":"SliceC",
>               "Ring":"3",
>               "ScaleUnit":"001",
>               "Host":"AGSFE_IN_70",
>               "ADSiteName":"NEU"
>            }
>         }      Duration:184.823      Strict-Transport-Security:      max-age=31536000 Cache-Control:      private Date:Wed,
>         03      Oct 2018 06:24:41      GMT Content-Type:application/json
>      }
>   }

I have created my own plan to create tasks and assign them accordingly. This application used to work without any issue but suddenly it started throwing this issue.

This issue only occurs on the update, other functions like the read, create and delete work without any issue.

I have full office 365 admin rights, so it is not admin related issues. I have looked at the Graph Api on Git Hub to see possible causes of this problem. In the git hub it states if a particular code is shown it can be referenced to the cause of the problem but there is no code provided

[Planner Api Documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/resources/planner_overview.md)

Any help would be appreciated to solve this issue

Comment: According to your description, we couldn't located the issue. We can try it on the MS Graph Explore with the `{taskID}` to get more information for the error. And you can provide the error.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved through trial and error.

The problem with it was due to me trying to modify the PlanId which i found out cannot be modified on update.

Once the PlanId part was removed from the api post request it updated without any issue